# rails button_to :disabled => true still displays the button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display a button but in a disabled state,to show the user that they already saved an item.

I currently used something like:

```
<%= button_to 'Save', :disabled => item.is_saved? %>
```

The generated html looks like:

```
<form class="button-to" action="/results/save_item/748?class=buttons&amp;disabled=true" method="post"> 

<div><input type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="hidden" value="+TKyrnA9idfmCkwDycLjHIkSLNou6NMt8R4TI73RezU=" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
</form>
```

This disables the action by setting the disabled=true option.
However, the button is still displayed.
Is there a way to show the button in a disabled state if the condition is true?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<% if item.is_saved? %>
  <%= button_to 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would like to have it disabled. 
In the code you suggested, the button does not appear at all if is_saved? is true.

Comment: On your original code the button is not displayed if is_saved is true. So tell me the criteria that you want please.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough.
I would like to display a button but in a disabled state,to
show the user that they already saved it.

Instead, the code I originally posted does not have a button at all.
I would like a button but in a disabled state.

Answer (score 34):

You have to specify URL first or let it empty. In your case :disabled is a param[:disabled].

```
<%= button_to 'Save', {}, :disabled => item.is_saved? %>
```